# How to decide size of generated dataset in DAGGER agorithm

Tags: imitation-learning

In the DAGGER algorithm, how does one determine the number of samples required for one iteration of the training loop? [image]

Looking at the picture above, I understand initially, during the 1st iteration, the dataset D comes from pre-recorded samples and is very large (in the tens of thousands).

however, i'm confused about step 2. ***How large should Dπ be?***

[This post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/7736/in-imitation-learning-do-you-simply-inject-optimal-tuples-of-experience-s-a) explains that it is good idea to "anneal out" D0 during the subsequent iterations,
which I think means having two separate datasets, and sample proportionally from each during step 1 (which implies in step 4, it is Dπ that is being aggregated, not D), in that case, ***is there a maximum size for Dπ***?

I've already looked at [What does the number of required expert demonstrations in Imitation Learning depend on?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/23019/what-does-the-number-of-required-expert-demonstrations-in-imitation-learning-dep), which seems to explain Dπ can be determined using a formula. However, the formula involves terms such as discount factor `γ` and various other terms which I don't think applies in this case. The paper I'm trying to implement is [End-to-end Driving via Conditional Imitation Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02410.pdf)

Thanks for any help!